# Cleanup my javascript using a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have javascript code that pretty much does the same thing many times. Is there a way to make a function to clean this up a little bit?

The two things I'd like to make into a function are:

**bright()**

```
$(VARIABLE).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
$(VARIABLE).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

**light()**

```
$(VARIABLE).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 0);
$(VARIABLE).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
```

.

I want to be able to pass a variable to the function so I can change that specific part. I am new to javascript so I'll only be asking this sort of question once. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var subject;
$('.subject').mouseenter(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass(subject) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }
});
$('.subject').mouseleave(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass(subject) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 0);
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
    }
});


$('.english-link').click(function(){
    subject = 'english';
    $('.english').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.english').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('.math-link').click(function(){
    subject = 'math';
    $('.math').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.math').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('.electives-link').click(function(){
    subject = 'electives';
    $('.electives').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.electives').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('.history-link').click(function(){
    subject = 'history';
    $('.history').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.history').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('.science-link').click(function(){
    subject = 'science';
    $('.science').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.science').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('.languages-link').click(function(){
    subject = 'languages';
    $('.languages').find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    $('.languages').find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
});
```

Comment: this sort of "cleanup" is called Extract Method Refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$(VARIABLE).find('.info, img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

Instead of:

```
$(VARIABLE).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 1);
$(VARIABLE).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

This can be a used in general for click on `.english-link`, `.math-link` etc..

```
$('[class$=-link]').click(function(){
   subject = $(this).attr('class').replace("-link","");
   $('.'+ subject ).find('.info, img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

Comment: I understand how this works for the most part. I don't want to just be copy and pasting code I don't fully understand. Could you explain the first line? `$('[class$=-link]')`

Comment: Sure.., It gets all elements that has `class` name ending with `-link`. See **[here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** for details and other similar selector options

Answer (score 2):

A function in JavaScript looks like this:

```
function myFunction(myParameter, mySecondParameter)
    console.log('You can now use data that was passed to the function through ' + myParameter);
}

var passAVariable = 5;
myFunction('passingastring',passAVariable);
```

Try this:

```
$('.languages-link').click(function(){
    yourfunction('languages', true);
});

function yourfunction(subject, on){
    if ( on ) {
        $('.' + subject).find('.info, img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    } else {
        $('.' + subject).find('.info').fadeTo('fast', 0);
        $('.' + subject).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I put the function outside of $(document).ready?
Whats the best practice for placing functions? The start or end of the script?

Comment: I put my functions inside the $(document).ready() function, I'm not sure what will happen if you put it outside.